# function pointer in c - understanding

Tags: c, function, pointers, bit-manipulation

I reading the code below, the first segment calls `read_temperature`, which reads a temperature sensor.

I'm trying to understand it.

1. Is `read_temperature()` a pointer to a function? What is the benefit of this?
2. `read_temperature` takes the address of length?
3. Why is it necessary to initialise tempbuff[] to all zeros using `memset()`.
4. What does `temp_reading&0xff` do?
5. Why is it necessary to do `*templength = 5;` at the end?

static int length;
static unsigned address

```
address = (unsigned int)read_temperature(& length);  
PRINTF("Temperature [%x] and its length is [%d] \r\n",address,length);
```

Second segment:

```
uint8_t tempbuff[8];

uint8_t * read_temperature(int *templength)
{

}
```

Comment: "What does temp_reading&0xff do" ... this seems to indicate your problem is not specifically about this "function pointer" but you Do Not Know C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `read_temperature` is a function that returns a pointer to an `uint8_t`.

As for the argument, passing arguments in C is done *by value*, meaning the value is copied into the argument variable. To emulate *pass by reference* a pointer to a variable is used, that way the function can dereference the pointer to access what the pointer is pointing to (the variable in the calling function). So when the function is doing `*templength = 5` it is setting the variable `length` in the calling function to the value `5`.

The initialization of the buffer is *probably* so it's no values from previous calls or calls to other functions that uses the same global buffer.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, `read_temperature` is an ordinary function that *returns* a pointer.
2. `templength` is passed as a pointer so that `read_temperature` can change the target in the caller, as it does at the bottom when it sets it to 5.
3. Since the first 5 elements are being manually set, the `memset` call is really only needed for the last 3 elements.  It also makes it easier to adjust the portion being set without worrying about the other elements.
4. `temp_reading&0xff` is masking the low-order 8 bits of `temp_reading`, forcing the rest of it to 0.  It's a bitwise AND operation.
5. As mentioned earlier, it's telling the caller how much of `tempbuff` is defined.  The caller passes the address of an `int` variable, and upon return that variable contains 5.